# Disabled network card and turn off Network Discovery so why is Windows still looking for network or connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ethernet

I am confused and this is driving me crazy:

I have two network drives attached to a network router that connects to my computer via LAN/Ethernet.

Every time the computer reboots, it takes about 5 minutes to connect and for programs to become response.

So I unplug the Ethernet cable and unplug all the drives and router, I then disable the network adapter.

To my dismay, when I restarted the computer the same thing happens, I get a message saying *"Cannot connect to network."* But I am confused, did I not disable everything?

How do I stop windows from trying to connect to anything? This never happens until I set up those drives via the router.

Thanks

Comment: Did you disable **all** network adapters from Control panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings ? If you did that, can you post screenshots of that message to clarify a bit what's wrong? This is your goal, correct me if I'm wrong;
Those 2 network drives are allways connected to the roter, which is allways on, with ethernet cable connected to the computer. When Windows boots up, it automatically and instantly connects to the network.¸ I posted this as answer because I couldn't post it as comment, but I still waanted to help.

Comment: I have a single Network Adapter and it is disabled. All File Sharing are turned off, Network discovery is also turned off. My goal is to avoid the long lag when windows starts up, which is caused by identifying the network. the circle goes round and round until a connection is established.

Comment: Maybe network misconfiguration causes lag. If you use DHCP Server, set  IP address in adapter properties to be obtained automatically. And if you don't, use static IP address in adapter properties. You can find that properties by right clicking the adapter > Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) > Properties